# All series on a given axis must be of the same data type for line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, linechart

I'm working on line chart using a `google js` and I have given some sample values for testing and I'm getting the error

```
All series on a given axis must be of the same data type
```

**Script**

```
 function drawChart() {
            // var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Value');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
            data.addRows([
                           [2008,'Value1',36],
                           [2009,'Value2',27],
                           [2010,'Value3',39]
            ]);
            var options = {
                title: "Company Performance Product Category Wise",
                pointSize: 5
            };
            var lineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            lineChart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px">
        </div>
```

Comment: I cannot find where this code is using Highcharts. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

works fine with only two columns...

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
data.addRows([
 ['2008',36],
 ['2009',27],
 ['2010',39]
]);
```